# c# TransactionScope time out

Tags: c#

In my c code im using a transaction scope.

But it gives the timeout exception after 10mins as below;

```
System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.BeginCommit(InternalTransaction tx, Boolean asyncCommit, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.InternalDispose()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()
```

I have following configuration in my web.config file;

```
  <system.transactions>
    <defaultSettings timeout="22:00:00" />
  </system.transactions>
```

Why Im still getting this timeout? How to fix this issue? please advice me.

Comment: Are you calling a query that takes that long to finish?

Comment: @3dd- I connect to different databases and it takes time.

Comment: @NewDeveloper using ? entity framework ?

Comment: @Webruster-Im just running SQL text

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get rid of it by making sure that the timeout of the transactionscope is longer than the command timeout.

Try Changing **transaction scope** to something like this:

```
new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)) //you already defined in web config  so it's fine
```

If you are using the entity to connect to database set an explicit timeout on your context. Should be something like:

```
myContext.CommandTimeout = 30; //This is seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the `machineSettings/maxTimeout` value in your `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config` file (you may need to alter this path if you're using the 32bit CLR or a different version).

This value limits the effective timeout, every timeout you set (either via `defaultSettings` or in code via `TransactionScopeOptions`) will be capped to this value. The "default" is 10 minutes.

You can search the web for "machineSettings maxTimeout" for a couple of related blog entries.